# Show that $f(x,y)=\frac{xy^6}{x^4+y^8}$ if $(x,y)\neq 0 $ and $f(0,0)=0$ is not differentiable.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I know that $f$ is not continuous at $0$ since $f(h^2,h)\to 1/2$ as $h\to0$. Although the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$ is continuous. Consider $$\frac {f(h,k)-f(0,0)-(0,0)\cdot(h,k)}{\lVert (h,k) \rVert}=\frac{\frac{hk^6}{h^4+k^8}}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=\frac{hk^6}{(h^4+k^8)\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$
I know that $\lvert\frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\rvert$ is bounded and $lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\lvert \frac{k^6}{h^4+k^8}  \rvert$ does not exist. Can I conclude that $lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{hk^6}{(h^4+k^8)\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$ does not exist and prove that $f$ is not differentiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is not complete. Put $h=k^{3}$; you will get the limit as $1$ in this case. Since the limit is $0$ along $h=0$ we see that the function is not differentiable.

Comment: thank!! I got it.